# Fix date format to not show time on BoundColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, date-formatting, boundcolumn

I am trying to change the format of the date to only show the date and not the time in a BoundColumn on a DataGrid but nothing I have tried has worked so far.

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="InvoiceDate" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"/>
```

I also tried:

```
DataFormatString="{0:dd-M-yyyy}"
DataFormatString="{0:d}"
DataFormatString="{0:MMM-d-yyy}"
```

Comment: You could do this in your code behind.

Comment: Tested it with a DataGrid Control. It works, no time is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formatting string I use in my table which only shows the date:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date"
     SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
```

An interesting caveat is that this renders the date as if it were formatted with `dd-MM-yyyy` but regional settings might have a role to play in this.

Comment: No didn't work, it's still showing the time on the grid.

Comment: Please update your question and show us a sample of the datetime values you're working with. I have a feeling that they aren't actually datetime values, but string values instead

Comment: The field is datetime in the database and on the grid it shows as 03/06/2017 00:00:00

Comment: Just wondering if adding HtmlEncode="false" within that control help? and since I don't know other idea, probably try DataFormatString="{0:d}" -- this is a short-hand version for date, but yours should have worked too.